# selenium wait function is not working

Tags: python, selenium

I have written functional test using selenium in python as follows:

```
self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)
self.browser.find_element_by_id("upload").click()
self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)
find_text_on_page(self, "some string")
```

but it's not working.I have given second implicit function to load the page but still I could not find the required string on that page hence it's failed.Can anyone give another solution so that selenium can wait to pass the test without failing?

Note : I don't want to use any explicit functions like wait.until or time.sleep().

Comment: Should not the wait statement be before the findelement statement?

Comment: it should be like this `self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)
self.browser.find_element_by_id("upload").click()`

Comment: Edited the question please check..

Comment: What do you mean still failed?? Is there any exception?? Need to share `find_text_on_page()` as well. And let us know why do you not want to use explicit wait??